# Why does removal of empty lines from multiline string in PowerShell fail using Replace function?

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I am loading HTML emails and at first I remove the HTML tags, I replace each `&nbsp;` by a space and I reduce the double spaces by a single space - that works.

But now I have a lot of empty lines which I cannot remove. I have seen the examples which remove empty lines while reading a file, but I don't have any empty lines before I remove the HTML tags and the spaces.

I do:

```
$m = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("$emailFolder\$fName")
$m = $m -replace "<((?!@).)*?>" # removes all html tag but not adr: <John.Doe@Doe.com>
$m = $m -replace "&nbsp;"," "
$m = $m.Replace('  ',' ').Replace('  ',' ').Replace('  ',' ')
$m = $m.Replace('`r','').Replace('`n`n','`n').Replace('`n`n','`n') # does nothing :(
```

I tried various version, none of them removed the empty lines. Any idea, how I can achieve that?

Beside that I tried to use the regex multiplier to find spaces in a row and failed.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
$m = $m.Replace(' +',' ')  # does not work
$m = $m.Replace('\s+',' ') # does not work either
```

Comment: It should be `<((?!@).*?)>` or `<((?!@)).*?>`

Comment: BTW, `(?!@).` is just `[^@]`

Comment: empty lines are `[\n\r]+`

Comment: I have some Perl-experience before I have to move to Windows. In Perl (Unix) you can define a multile-regex-search which is not possible in Powershell as far as I know. If I search e.g. for a pattern in the email body I code with .+ (which should be greedy and should give the last occurrence, that's how it is in Perl) but Powershell matches only the first occurrence and then stops searching at the end of this line :(

Comment: @hjpotter92 & @Mofi \r and \n do not work - as far as I know - in powershell! You have to use `r`n but it isn't working, may be due to what I have written in the previous comment

Comment: I think the problem is Powershell specific - in Perl e.g. I wouldn't have any problem!!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want to remove all line breaks, just "empty" lines (lines that consist of nothing but whitespace).

Consider this sample string:

```
$multiLine = "Line 1`r`nLine 2`nLine 3`r`n`r`n  `n `t `r`nLine 7`r`n"
```

When displayed, it will look like this on screen:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3



Line 7
```

Line 4 is actually a blank line, with nothing but a CRLF. Line 5 is a space followed by a single LF, Line 6 is a space, a tab, a space, then a CRLF. I mixed line endings because HTML can be a mess; it's good to be prepared for anything!

To handle all of these, you can do a replace like this:

```
$multiLine -creplace '(?m)^\s*\r?\n',''
```

## What Does This Do?

1. `-creplace` is just the case-sensitive version of `-replace` (I like to be explicit).
2. `(?m)` is an inline way to set [regular expression modes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html). The `m` mode stands for multi-line, and it lets the `^` and `$` anchors match the beginning/end of each line in a string (rather than the beginning and end of the string). **This is the key to your issue, I think.**
3. We're using `^` to match the beginning of each line, then matching 0 or more whitespace using the `\s` class, which includes tab.
4. We're matching an optional carriage return (for Windows line breaks), followed by a line break. We don't need to match multiples of these because `^` will catch them throughout the string.

### The Resulting Output

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 7
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me.  This does though:   | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" }

Comment: Just wanted to point out the reply by BSUK does not apply to the question asked by OP. The solution supplied by briantist would not work for BSUK because BSUK was working with a string array as opposed to a single string with multiple lines like the OP was working with. The solution provided by briantist does indeed work for a single string with multiple lines.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work:

```
$m -replace '(?ms)(?:\r|\n)^\s*$'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the backtick inside single quotes, I got the same failure/result until I tried double quotes.  I believe the problem lies in how the backtick is parsed while inside single quotes as opposed to not being parsed when from double quotes.

I'll say this is a feature and not a bug.

```
$m = "`r`n`n`r`r`n`r`n"

$m = $m.Replace("`r",'')
$m = $m.Replace("`n",'')

$m
```

Comment: Just tried with double quotes (again), no change, all the empty lines are still there :( hmm, it's a buggy feature.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post however I found another post that has an easier method and others may benefit.
Your array that you imported using get-content for example

```
$array = Get-content C:\list.txt
```

$array displays

Name 1
Name 2

Name 3

Name 4

Do this...

```
$array = $array | where-object {$_}
```

This will output as you were after.

Source is http://techibee.com/powershell/remove-empty-items-from-array-in-powershell/2431

Comment: This applies to string arrays as opposed to a single string with multiple lines like the OP was talking about

Answer (score 0):

This works on me (what I mean is using the -replace).

```
$message.Body = (Get-Content "C:\Documents\Folder\email.txt") | ForEach-Object {
        $_ -replace ('\[NAME\]' , $name)`
           -replace ('\[AGE\]'  , $age)`
           -replace ('\[CITY\]' , $city)`
           -replace ('\[STATE\]' , $state)`
           -replace ('\[POSTAL\]' , $postal)


        }
```

Comment: This applies to string arrays as opposed to a single string with multiple lines like the OP was talking about

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the flag: **-Raw**

```
$m = Get-Content "$emailFolder\$fName" -Raw #<- You need to include this
$m = $m -creplace '\s+', ' '
```